# Network i/o in parallel for a FUSE file system

Tags: linux, file, kernel, system, fuse

**My motivation**

I'd love to write a distributed file system using FUSE. I'm still designing the code before I jump in. It'll be possibly written in C or Go, the question is, how do I deal with network i/o in parallel?

**My problem**

More specifically, I want my file system to write locally, and have a thread do the network overhead asynchronously. It doesn't matter if it's slightly delayed in my case, I simply want to avoid slow writes to files because the code has to contact some slow server somewhere.

**My understanding**

There's two ideas conflicting in my head. One is that the FUSE kernel module uses the ABI of my program to hijack the process and call the specific FUSE function names I implemented (sync or async, w/e), the other is that.. the program is running, and blocking to receive events from the kernel module (which I don't think is the case, but I could be wrong).

Whatever it is, does it means I can simply start a thread and do network stuff? I'm a bit lost on how that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do any hijacking. The FUSE kernel module registers as a filesystem provider (of type fusefs). It then services read/write/open/etc calls, by dispatching them to the user-mode process. When that process returns, the kernel module gets the return value, and returns from the corresponding system call.

If you want to have the server (i.e. user mode process) by asynchronous and multi-threaded, all you have to do is dispatch the operation (assuming it's write - you can't parallelize input this way) to another thread in that process, and return immediately to FUSE. That way, your user mode process can, at its leisure, write out to the remote server.

You could similarly try to parallelize read, but the issue here is that you won't be able to return to FUSE (and thus release the reading process) until you have at least the beginning of the data read.

Comment: That make sense. Writes can be async in a thread, but reads would still suffer from the same problem since when I have the answer from the server, I'd have returned to FUSE a long time ago. Fortunately, the design of my file system doesn't need this. Thanks for the help, tried your advices today and I'm apparently back on the right track!